# Why can't numba.prange function work properly with a tuple argument?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to run the following code on visual studio code:

```
from numba import njit , prange
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel = True)

def parallel_sum(A):
   sum = 0.0
   for j in prange(A.shape[0]):
      sum += A[j]
   return sum

X = np.random.normal(size=(10,3))
F = np.zeros(X.shape[0])
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    F[i] = parallel_sum(X[i,:])
    print(F[i])
```

I got an error message

> Non-iterable value prange(A.shape[0]) is used in an iterating context

I know A.shape[0] returns a tuple value. So, I tried the following code:

```
    def parallel_sum(A):
       sum = 0.0
       k = int(A.shape[0])
       for j in prange(k):
          sum += A[j]
       return sum
```

But the problem still persists. There is a similar question in stackoverflow.com [where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352315/numba-prange-example-does-not-work) a solution is discussed. However, this solution also doesn't work. I didn't find any other resource in the internet also.

Comment: I ran this code and I got `-1.5102037358994846`, `4.807169122724803`, ...

Comment: It also works for me (not the newest but numba 0.45) if it doesn't work for you with the most current numba version consider to open an bug-report.

Comment: Which numba version do you use `print(nb.__version__)` ? This should work, but a parallel sum does not really make sense since this problem is memory bandwidth limited. In most cases this should be slower. (It is better to use a single thread version with fastmath=True for SIMD-vectorization)

Comment: @max9111 can you give me more resource on this "SIMD-vectorization" thing?

Comment: @ead my version is 0.50.1. okay, I will open a bug report